# How to Edit files using web application

Tags: web, jython

All,

I have a requirement where user would like to edit the files using web application. I know there would be a concurrency issues. But i want to know if there is a way to do it efficiently in the web application, may be using Jython or any other framework.

Any help or other framework which can help with this is really appreciable.

Comment: What files? What kind of files?

Comment: those are properties files and some xml files, which are out of the web content folder or otherway it is not the part of the war package.

Comment: So, what have you tried, or found? There are plenty of ways to edit files using web applications.

Comment: the only issue i see to edit file is the concurrency issue. And i dont want to go with creation of multiple files for each user and the merge those all. Let me know if there is more efficient way of doing it.

Comment: Well, then you should rephrase your question to match your last statement. As for the concurrency issue, I'll post an answer to deal specifically with it.

Comment: @Feign if you have link can you please share the link, i am not sure how i can edit the question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution to the concurrency issue you talk about is to save a datetime stamp each time the file is edited from anywhere.

Now, if a user tries to save his changes to a file, check the datetime stamp and make sure that the current edit's datetime stamp is greater than the last edit. If it is not, then you know the file has been changed and the user should reload the file, make his changes again, then attempt to save again.